# Flutter web icons getting Error 404 on apache live server

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

All the icons of my flutter website is getting error 404 on live server

[image: inspect element console]

but I did pushed the entire generated "web" folder to my apache server, the structure of the "web" folder is as below

[image: web folder structure]

However, if I move the "icons" folder into "assets" folder and change all the paths in my index.html, it worked like a charm. It seems that the "icons" folder is the only folder which hits 404. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think the apache server already has an alias for "icons" so that's why it is not redirecting to the icons folder here. I have also renamed the icons folder to "images".

Answer (score 0):

You can try update asset path to folder icon on pubspec.yaml ?

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icons/ -> let change at here for you folder icons*
    - assets/images/
```